# Why do we train the threshold as a weight in neural networks?

Tags: neural-network, training

Why do we train the threshold as a weight?

I understand the process of how to do it (the bias and augmented weight vector) but do not get the importance or practical applications of doing so.

Comment: Short answer: "Some things cannot be learned without a bias.", for longer answers see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480650/role-of-bias-in-neural-networks